# Finding largest disc where the series $e^z$ about $z_0 = \pi i$ is valid

Tags: complex-analysis, power-series

I was hoping to find the power series expansion of $e^z$ about $z_0 = \pi i$.

I got this as following for the power series:
$$e^z=-\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\dfrac{1}{n!} (z-\mathrm i\pi)^n$$

So how would I find the largest disc? Would this just be the radius of convergence? Would $|z| < \pi$ make sense?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can use the ratio test on the series of absolute values of the terms.

Comment: This is entire so converges everywhere